# SwiftUI Navigation Title Space

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Hey guys I had a quick question hopefully you guys are able to help. Im using swiftUI to make this app. When I use NavigationLink to get to different views there's always this extra space that I can't get rid of. I've tried

'.navigationbarIsHidden(true)'

but that just doesn't work at all

code for view 1:

```
struct MenuView: View{
    var column = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160), spacing: 20)]
    @StateObject var cartManager =  CartManager()
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                    
                    
                    LazyVGrid(columns: column, spacing: 20){
                        
                        ForEach(productList, id: \.id){ product in
                            ProductCard(product: product)
                                .environmentObject(cartManager)
                        }
                    }.padding()
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
                .navigationTitle("Menu")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination:
                                CartView()
                                .environmentObject(cartManager)
                        ){
                            
                            CartButton(numberOfProducts: cartManager.products.count)
                            
                        }
                    }//TOOLBARITEM
                    
                   
                    
                }//TOOLBAR
            }//VSTACK
            
        }//NAVVIEW
        
    }}
```

code for view 2:

```
struct CartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var cartManager: CartManager
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
               // Text("Cart")
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                    
                    if(cartManager.products.count > 0){
                        
                        ForEach(cartManager.products, id: \.id){
                            product in
                            
                            ProductRow(product: product)
                                .environmentObject(cartManager)
                            
                        }
                        
                        VStack {
                            HStack{
                                Text("Tax:")
                                    .font(.title)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("$\(cartManager.tax, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .bold()
                            }.padding()
                            
                            
                            
                            HStack{
                                Text("Tip:")
                                    .font(.title)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("$\(cartManager.tip, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .bold()
                            }.padding()
                            
                            
                            HStack{
                                Text("Total:")
                                    .font(.title)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("$\(cartManager.total, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .bold()
                            }
                            
                        }.padding()
                        
                    }else{
                        Spacer(minLength: 300)
                        Image(systemName: "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw.fill")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        Text("Your cart is empty!")
                            .font(.title2)
                        Text("Add things to your order to continue!")
                            .font(.title2)
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
                
                
               
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Your Order")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
        }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The extra space is usually caused by multiple navigation views but we can't help with the information you have provided.

Comment: sorry I thought I had posted full code

Comment: Get rid of the navigation view in cart view